# Using SCOM to collect Sharepoint usage statistics?

Tags: sharepoint, scom, system-center

We’re running System Center 2012 with SharePoint Management Pack installed. It’s not really used in anger, but recently we have been asked to output stats on user logins and concurrent connections from the reporting console.

Having reviewed the guide for the 2013 SharePoint MP, I can’t see any monitors or rules that would enable this. Unless I’m missing something?

Does this mean it would have to be done at a Windows server level, and if so what are the monitors that would enable the stat to be collected in the Data Warehouse?

Any help appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I afraid that SharePoint MP doesn't collect this information (I doublechecked on mpwiki.viacode.com - nothing like that) so you are right that you need to find what window perf counters can unveil it for you...may be Web Services-->Current Connections will work.

Roman.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I too have come to the same conclusion. I'll look into the Windows counters.